# Acoustic potential and mean acoustic intensity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, momentum, acoustics

I'm trying to deal with the following question:

I have a sphere, radius $r = r_0$ and a time varying pressure at the surface:

$p(t) = p_0 + \tilde{p_0}(t)H(t) $

Where $p_0$ is a constant and $H(t)$ is the Heaviside function. A compressible gas is at rest when $t=0$. Question:

- What is the acoustic velocity potential outside the sphere?
- If $\tilde{p}(t)$ is time harmonic with constant angular frequency $\omega$, what is the mean acoustic intensity over one period of the disturbance?

What is the proper way to do this? Start with the momentum equation?